# How to redirect root domain to subfolder (with https) and rest of addon domains to subfolders (without https)

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, subdirectory

How to redirect root domain to subfolder (with HTTPS) and rest of other addon domains to subfolders (without HTTPS).

Currently I have this `.htaccess` in root which redirects with HTTPS to `the-main-subfolder` ok. But my other addon domain, say `domain2` also gets redirected to `the-main-subfolder`.

I would like to redirect `domain2` to `the-domain2-subfolder` **without HTTPS**.

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch ^/$ /the-main-subfolder/
```

I am not sure if this code is correct as it might me using a wildcard. I got this code from searching on net but there are so many suggestions that I am confused now!

**In summary:** My main hosting account in root should go to https://www.domain1.co.uk/the-main-subfolder when user types in domain1.co.uk in browser and my addon domain http://domain2.co.uk should go to http://www.domain2.co.uk/the-domain2-subfolder.

Comment: What do you refer to by "root domain" and by "addon domains"?

Comment: A root domain is when you buy hosting, the default domain that is always pointing to public_html folder in cPanel filemanager. Add-on domain are some other domains that you can add afterwards to hosting account and it is preferred to point to index file in say in the directory /the-domain2-subfolder

Comment: So your hosting package includes a domain and you purchased additional domains? Is that what you try to express?

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional `RewriteCond`s to define specific redirections:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/the-main-subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.org$ 
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ /example1\.org-subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.org$ 
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ /example2\.org-subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host1\.example\.org$ 
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ /host1\.example\.org-subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host2\.example\.org$ 
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ /host2\.example\.org-subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I added a few examples to demonstrate the redability of explicit implementation and that you can do that for both, separate domains and hostnames (sometimes incorrectly called "subdomains"). I would always prefer such explicit notation over generic approaches since you can individually modify things, for example for testing or debugging purposes. Except if you are in a mass hosting situation obviously, then a database based approach makes sense.

Note that the redirection for what you call the "root domain" (`example.org` here) has a second `RewriteCond` now. Both conditions are `AND`-combined per default.

For safety you probably also want to add some more rules to redirect requests to something like `https://example.org/host1.example.org-subfolder` to the specific domain name, since according to your description you are limited to a single file tree in your hosting account. Same for request to `http://test1.example.org/test1.example.org-subfolder/...` to eliminate the literal folder name.

Oh, and a warning: the above syntax works for `.htaccess` style files only. If you have access to the real host configuration then you should *always* prefer to place such rules in there. However you need a slightly changed syntax then. `.htaccess` style rules are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only offered as a last option for those without access to the host configuration.

Comment: thanks @arkascha - I am just trying this on now! Great explanation - Thank you!

Comment: Ok - I tried your suggestion but it was giving me error 500 on all domains. So I tweaked it to minimal version: 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]'

Comment: What error exactly do you get? What is written in your http servers error log file? Error 500 is very vague...

Comment: Sure, error 550 always is an "internal server error", that is the definition of http status 500. My question was what the actual error was, you can read that in your http servers error log file, not somewhere in your browser.

Comment: All addon domain work with above minimal lines but the only problem is that the main domain1 is not redirected to subdirectory /the-main-subfolder

Comment: Changed the redirection rule for the main domain to also rewrite to a subfolder.

Comment: Well the error is due to misconfigured .htaccess and it works if i remove some lines

Comment: OK, giving up. I don't see why we should _guess_ what the issue is if all you'd have to do is look into that error log file...

Comment: ok - thanks - i will apply Changed the redirection rule as you mentioned! That was great help to put me in right direction! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/the-main-subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]`

Thanks @arkascha - Everything now works as expected with the above code. I suppose we do not need to mention so called add-on domains here at all because cPanel handles the sub-directories for them internally when we add subsequent domains on the hosting package (i.e. addon domains)!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update that my previous solution partially works as it has few niggles/bugs. So went back to the drawing board and suddenly realised I was unnecessarily trying too hard!!

Deleted the old htaccess file first and followed instruction below..

The solution is already provided by cPanel in something called "Redirects" in Panel Icons.

I just had to enter everything in user interface text boxes like choose domainname = "domain1", old folder = "\", new folder = "https://www.domain1.co.uk/the-main-subfolder" - And just click create the redirect. In doing so it creates a .htaccess file itself automatically. I am sharing this below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain1\.co\.uk\/the-main-subfolder\/" [R=301,L]
```